Seeing which key is pressed on peripheral device in HEX
I am looking for a way to see what keys I have pressed (or am pressing) on a Windows peripheral device (Thrustmaster Shifter) in hexadecimal.
I can find software for keyboard presses, but this doesn't help me.
is there existing software for this, or any other way to do this in Windows10?
why I need this:
I play a game, Snowrunner (car game), which does not let you shift gears manually.
I am using a mod, which enables you to shift manually.
to configure this, you need to input the hex value for the key you want to use for
shifting up, down, 1st gear 2nd gear and so on...
currently I am using:
left_shift 0xa2 and
left_ctrl 0xa0
on my keyboard
for shifting up and down,
but I want to switch to using a wheel and shifter,
so now I need to know what the hex values of each gear of my Thrustmaster shifter are.
the game only detects wheels and pedals, but unfortunately no shifter or handbrake.

Did you try AutoHotkey? https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/KeyHistory.htm
